# What kind of authentication does PDO use on Postgres?

Tags: php, postgresql, authentication, pdo

I try to connect to my database using this code:

```
Db::$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$db;host=$host;port=$port", $user, $pass, $opt);
```

and it fails with:

> FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

When I use the same credentials on the command line, it works fine:

```
psql -h127.0.0.1 -Upostgres --password -ddatabase1 -p5432
Password for user postgres: 
psql (10.5)
Type "help" for help.

database1=#
```

Why is PDO using ident auth, even though I explicitly use a username and password?

**Update** I found that the commandline also fails when using `localhost` as hostname. Apparently `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `localhost` as a host, PDO (or Postgres?) might use IPv6 to connect. And that line was like this in my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

So, that is why `ident` was used.